# How to remove first element in multidimentional array

Tags: javascript

I have a 2d array called Data which contains rows and columns of a CSV. I want to remove the first row which is the CSV's headers.

I've tried `data[0].splice(1, 1);` but that's not working for me.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Use `array_shift`, read manuals.

Comment: You are definitely doing it wrong because you are removing items from the first row, not the first row itself.

Comment: How would I remove the first row itself?

Comment: If `data[0]` is the first row, then you just want [`data.splice(0, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: http://jsperf.com/splice-vs-shift use data.shift()